# Change `character` to `numeric` in time series

Tags: r, time-series

Suppose I have the following data set.

```
structure(c("0.233632449583826", "0.252105485477729", "0.591295809149662", 
"0.0901324567177099", "-0.0423290120373304", "0.0363874105632916", 
"-0.136952003053153", "0.451355935617868", "-0.291897852322839", 
"0.287789031880016", "-2.1", "-1.4", "-2.6", "1.9", "-0.7", "1.4", 
"-0.6", "-1.3", "-1.4", "0"), .Dim = c(10L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    NULL, c("Return", "CI")), .Tsp = c(1985, 1985.75, 12), class = c("mts", 
"ts", "matrix"))
```

I am trying to calculate descriptive statistics and correlation between `Return` and `CI` using `describe` and `cor`. However, it gives the following error:

```
Error in describe(x) : non-numeric argument to 'describe'
```

It seems that the values in my data set are `character` not `numeric`. I tried `as.numeric` and `data.matrix` but still gives `FALSE` to `is.numeric` test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `x` is the object then convert it to numeric; however, that will cause the attributes to be dropped so add them back in:

```
xx <- as.numeric(x)
attributes(xx) <- attributes(x)
```

You might want to investigate how you wound up with this in the first place.  There might be something else wrong too.

Comment: I am trying to investigate that, however, I am quite sure all issues comes from importing from Excel in the first place.